How can I used mason installed debugpy with nvim-dap-python?
The instructions at nvim-dap-python recommends to install debugpy into a dedicated virtualenv, and the pass the path of the python executable in that virtualenv to nvim-dap-python with:
require('dap-python').setup('~/.virtualenvs/debugpy/bin/python')

I noticed that debugpy can be installed via mason.nvim (and automate the install with mason-tool-installer). But how can I use the Mason installed debugpy (:MasonInstall debugpy) with nvim-dap-python? Where is the path to the debugpy virtualenv in this case?

When you run :MasonInstall debugpy it will be installed on the standard directory "data" (vim.fn.stdpath('data'), see :h stdpath()), the full path would be something like /Users/ecerulm/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/debugpy/venv/bin/python where /Users/ecerulm/.local/share/nvim is the stdpath('data').
So then to configure this path in nvim-dap-python you can use
    local python_path = table.concat({ vim.fn.stdpath('data'),  'mason', 'packages', 'debugpy', 'venv', 'bin', 'python'}, '/'):gsub('//+', '/')
    require('dap-python').setup(python_path)

The table.concat() and gsub could be replaced with vim.fn.joinpath() if you are using Neovim 0.10.x (that would be released around May 2024)
